# Strange reduce behaviour

Tags: python

When I execute this code in python 2.6

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x+[y], [1,2,3],[])
```

I get [1, 2, 3] as expected. 
But when I execute this one (I think it is equivalent to previous)

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x.append(y), [1,2,3],[])
```

I get an error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Why these two lines of code do not give the same result?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`x.append(y)` is not equivalent to `x+[y]`; `append` modifies a list in place and returns nothing, while `x+[y]` is an expression that returns the result.

Comment: Thank you. Now I see that I should have read documentation more thoughtfully.

Answer (score 7):

`reduce` calls the function and uses the return value as the new result. `append` returns `None`, and therefore the next `append` invocation fails. You could write

```
def tmpf(x,y):
   x.append(y)
   return x
reduce(tmpf, [1,2,3], [])
```

and get the correct result. However, if the result is a list of the same size as the input, you're not looking for reduce: The result of reduce should usually be a single value. Instead, use [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) or simply

```
[x for x in [1,2,3]]
```

Comment: I wouldn't define `tmpf` this way, as it has the unexpected side effect of modifying the initializer (last argument to `reduce`).

Comment: @aix Added further cautioning against using `reduce` to produce a list. You could insert `if len(x) == 0: x = []` in `tmpf`, but that only underscores that `reduce` is not the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 6):

The function argument to `reduce` is expected to **return** the result of the operation.

`x+[y]` does that, whereas `x.append(y)` doesn't (the latter modifies `x` and returns `None`).

Answer (score 0):

Just to explain the error message:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`

The expression

`reduce(lambda x,y: x.append(y), [1,2,3],[])`

is equivalent to

`[].append(1).append(2).append(3)`

Since `[].append(1)` does not return a value, i.e. it returns `None` it tries to execute (in the second step)

`None.append(2)`

which results in the error message `Nonetype object has no attribute append`